# Backbone + Backbone.Marionette / Region Management etc

Tags: animation, backbone.js, marionette

I have a build coming up, where I have the following JSON-feeds:

- site.com/json/`items`
- site.com/json/`item/:id`

I'm using Backbone.Marionette and Backbone's router to manage which view is being shown (index or detail), but have 2 things I'm having some trouble figuring out:

- My client wants to show 'previous' and 'next' buttons on the detail-view
- Preferable they'd want to animate this sort of like how [Reveal.js](http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/#/) shows next/previous items.

How would I go about getting the "next" or "previous" ItemView, and how would I determine where to animate the next ItemView in from? I want to go about this as DRY / smart as I can. Also when using the Back-button it should use the "reverse" animation, so that the transition appears natural when using browser's back button. So I think I should somehow determine whether we were already showing the ItemView, and if the current ItemView is before or after the requested ItemView. Is that the "right" way to do it?

Comment: What have you got so far? I'd be happy to help with any specific code problems you are running into. It is difficult to help without code to look at though.

Comment: It's mostly "aircode" on paper right now, I'm totally lost as to how to hook this all up. If you want I can work out the ItemView? Would that be most useful?